# Change gradient value in rasterrenderer for display of multiple raster files

Tags: qgis, raster, display

QGIS version 3.16.16-Hannover OS Version Linux Mint 19.3

I work with groups of Singleband rasters that I visualize by default with the Singleband gray render type.

I usually have 10 to 20 rasters and when I load them they by default are visualized with the color gradient option Black to White.

In my field the standard is WhiteToBlack so I need to change this parameter for all my rasters.

I am starting to learn how to use python scripts work but I am not there yet. Would anyone have a turnaround or a tip to set the color gradient of the rasterrender to WhiteToBlack to all my loaded files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling a lot, it seems I got the answer...

First I load all my files manually

Then I apply this script

```
mc=iface.mapCanvas() #create an instance of the map canvas
ltv=iface.layerTreeView() #create an instance of the Tree View
rlayers=mc.layers() #create a list with all the loaded and checked files (the ones I just loaded)

#run a loop to change the color scale from black to white to white to black and refresh map canvas and tree view

for rlayer in rlayers:
    rlayer.renderer().setGradient(QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer.WhiteToBlack)
    rlayer.triggerRepaint()
    ltv.refreshLayerSymbology(rlayer.id())
```

as I am just starting with pyQgis, any comment on the solution would be most welcome...